# Angular dropdown add option to fetched data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-options

I've been looking around on SO for quite some time, but none of the even remotely close questions to mine seem to contain an answer to this.

**The situation is the following:**

I'm populating a dropdown (or select, as you wish) using AngularJS (^1.6.2) with data fetched from the database. This data is put in this select using `ng-options` with everything correctly being set and all.

What I'm trying to achieve is that a `NULL` option gets added to this list of options, but **not** to the `$scope` object containing the fetched data.

I'll clarify with some code:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.name for item in items track by item.id" 
        ng-model="forms.formDataObject.item">
</select>
```

This generates a list of options, something like this:

```
<select ...>
  <option value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="3">Item 3</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I've tried to add a `NULL` option to this dropdown using the following Angular filter:

```
app.filter('addNullOption', () => {
    return (input) => {
        if (!input[0].null_option) {
            var emptyObj = angular.copy(input[0]);

            Object.keys(emptyObj).forEach((key) => {
                emptyObj[key] = null;
            });

            emptyObj.null_option = true;

            input.unshift(emptyObj);
        }
        return input;
    };
})
```

And then applying the filter in the `ng-options` as you would with other filters.

This works, but adds the `NULL` option to the `$scope` object, instead of it only being available in the `$scope` of this dropdown. I don't want this to happen, because other dropdowns throughout the application use the same `$scope` object for populating the dropdown, and they **shouldn't** have this `NULL` option available.

To recapitulate, this is my question: I would like to be able to add a `NULL` option to a pre-populated dropdown, **only** in the `$scope` of that specific dropdown.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning filter data to same array. Assign it to different array. This way original array will remain the same.

```
<select ng-options="item as item.name for item in sampleAr = ( items | filter : addNullOption) track by item.id" 
        ng-model="forms.formDataObject.item">
</select>
```

This might not be the best way to do this but i bang by head around multiple times but this is the only solution i came with. Hope this help

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.items = [{"id":1,"name":"sss","null_option":true},{"id":2,"name":"aaa"},{"id":3,"name":"fff"},{"id":4,"name":"asdas"}]
$scope.sampleAr =  angular.copy($scope.items)


$scope.addNullOption = ()=>{
 return (input) => {
        if (input.null_option) {
            $scope.items.splice(input,1)
        }
        return input;
    };
}

$scope.copys = function (item){
   return angular.copy(item);
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select ng-init="sampleAr = copys(items)"
 ng-options="item as item.name for item in sampleAr track by item.id" 
        ng-model="forms.formDataObject.item">
</select>
<div ng-init="items = items | filter :addNullOption() "> </div>
<br> 
{{items}}
<br> 
<br> 
{{sampleAr}}
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried your exact solution, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: can you post the `items` array

Comment: I eventually fixed the issue by applying a filter to not show the NULL option in other places I use this data object. But thank you for trying!